# Loop through sheets to copy/paste on to named sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The following code is not looping through to copy onto the "Archive" sheet.  Additionally, I would like it to add today's date and the sheet name in Columns A&B in the Archive sheet.

```
Sub ArchiveTrans()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SourceWB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Select source location and range
For Each ws In SourceWB.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Change Control" And ws.Name <> "Archive" Then
        ActiveSheet.Select
        Set destRng = Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End    (xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Copy selected range to last row
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A:AK" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=destRng

    End If
Next ws
With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `SourceWB` isn't set to anything

Comment: And `LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `Range("A:AK" & LastRow).Copy` are being performed on the `ActiveSheet` (because you haven't specified a specific worksheet) - you **probably** meant them to be `LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `ws.Range("A:AK" & LastRow).Copy`

Comment: And `Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` should be `Sheets("Archive").Cells(Sheets("Archive").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`.  And get rid of `ActiveSheet.Select` - it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm brand new to VBA, so learning as I go.